# What is the difference between GDM and Gnome-desktop?

Tags: desktop-environments, display-manager

As GDM is GNOME Display Manager but it installs the GNOME desktop also when I replaces it with LightDM So what is the difference between installing GDM or installing Gnome-desktop environment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Installing `gnome-desktop` gives you the GNOME desktop environment. You can access it through lightdm desktop manager (Ubuntu's default) even if you don't have `gdm`. On the other hand, `gdm` is merely login screen. Surprisingly enough, if you do `apt-cache show gdm` it reports that gnome-shell is one of the dependencies, but `apt-cache show gnome-desktop` reports that gdm is only a recommended package. Why is it so ? I don't know, and probably only the developers can tell you.

Comment: But installing GDM is giving me whole GNOME Desktop environment not just login-screen along with Ubuntu desktop and unity

Comment: @MuditKapil That's because gdm depends on gnome as it is said.

Comment: @MuditKapil Desktop environment can be stand alone. For example, I have gnome, unity, openbox, blackbox. Those packages don't care about what login screen you use. But desktop manager (the login screen) does care, apparently.

Comment: @Serg I think GDM is display manager with gnome-shell,the difference is between gnome-shell and gnome-desktop

Answer (score 6):

lightdm and GDM are both '[display managers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131496/what-is-lightdm-and-gdm)'.  They govern how and when your 'desktop environment' loads.

Gnome, KDE and XFCE are all examples of desktop environments, and should be compatible with both lightdm and GDM.

Comment: Who is downvoting? This is the correct answer.

Comment: @Pilot6 while technically correct, this answer isn't complete. The OP wants to know why installing gdm also gave him access to gnome-desktop. I will upvote this answer, but it misses the core of OP's question.

Comment: @MuditKapil lets not be rude in the comments. Just help people understand better what you exactly wanted. Everybody be peaceful :)